# How to plot the next period value of a variable against its past period in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am trying to plot a difference equation using R. I have the following MWE:

```
N <- 10 #periods
time <- c(0:N)
x <- rep(0,N)
x[1] <- 0.5 #initial value
E <- rep(0,N)
E[1] <- 1
#Parameters
c <- 1
K <- 1
p <- 200
q <- 0.01
g <- 0.1
eta <- 0.3

for (t in 1:N) {
  x[t+1] <- (1 + g - g*x[t]/K - q*E[t])*x[t]
  E[t+1] <- (1 + eta*(p*q*x[t]-c))*E[t]
}

p1 <- plot(x[t], x[t+1]) #I try this but clearly this does not work
p2 <- plot(x[0:N], x[1:N+1]) #this produces a diagram where x=y, a 45 degree line
```

p1 produces

[image]

and p2 produces

[image]

I am expecting the graph to look like a stable spiral. My question is, how do you properly plot the next period value of a variable against the current period? I am looking to plot

$$x_{t+1}(x_{t})$$

Comment: Side note: How disappointing that stack overflow does not have support for LaTeX when other SEs do. Are there any relevant Meta posts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems:

1.The N in your example is to small. To see the stable spiral set the N to 100 or 1000

2.Your plots show exactly what I would expect, but I don't think they do what you want to do ;)

p1 plots the second last element of `x` `x[t]` on the x axis (`t` is equal to `N` after the for loop) against the last element of `x` -> a single point.

p2 plots all elements of `x` except the last against all elements of `x` except the first, i.e. the value against itself with 1 lag -> points form almost a diagonal

But if you plot any of:

```
plot(time, E)
plot(time, x)
plot(E, x)
```

You get interesting plots, the last one drawing a spiral!

[image: E_vs_x_plot]